# 3D scatter plot with labels

Tags: plotting

I am doing 3-D scatter plot with labels and using the following code

```
data = {{0.879`, -0.093`, 0.08`}, {0.865`, 0.069`, -0.073`}, {0.863`, 
   0.086`, -0.144`}, {0.827`, -0.202`, 0.17`}, {0.768`, -0.233`, 
   0.127`}, {0.697`, 0.246`, 0.118`}, {0.691`, 
   0.306`, -0.276`}, {-0.641`, 0.316`, 0.541`}, {0.64`, -0.299`, 
   0.404`}, {0.058`, 0.869`, -0.014`}, {0.074`, 0.866`, 
   0.04`}, {-0.203`, 0.586`, 0.42`}, {-0.049`, 0.08`, 
   0.759`}, {0.174`, 0.02`, 0.723`}, {0.143`, -0.05`, 
   0.632`}, {-0.405`, 0.322`, 0.576`}}

labels = {{"Stylish"}, {"Fun"}, {"Exciting"}, {"Status"}, \
{"Performance"}, {"Powerful"}, {"Sports"}, {"Family"}, {"Luxurious"}, \
{"Outdoorsy"}, {"Rugged"}, {"Versatile"}, {"Safe"}, {"Comfortable"}, \
{"Dependable"}, {"Practical"}}

Show[Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[data]}], 
 Graphics3D[Text[#[[1]], 1.04 *# & /@ data] & /@ labels], 
 Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

However, what I got is a graph with labels crushed together, as shown below
[image]

I believe there is something wrong with this part of code `1.04 *# & /@ data`. What should I do to make each label appear besides each corresponding point? Thank you.

Comment: `Show[Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[data]}], 
 Graphics3D[
  Text[#[[1, 1]], 1.04*#[[2]]] & /@ Transpose@{labels, data}], 
 Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> 1]`

Comment: Debugging thing like this is easy if you just take the Text[...] /@ labels part and evaluate it in a cell of its own.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace Map with Thread.

```
Graphics3D[{{Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[data]}, 
  Thread[Text[Flatten[labels], 1.04 data]]}, Axes -> True, 
 BoxRatios -> 1]
```

However I would sugest you to create third list, which would adjust label position. Something like (here chosen randomly)

```
labelsRelativePositions = 
 Table[{RandomInteger[{-1, 1}], 
   RandomInteger[{-1, 1}]}, {Length[data]}];

Graphics3D[{{Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[data]}, 
  Thread[Text[Flatten[labels], 1.04 data, labelsRelativePositions]]}, 
 Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> 1]
```